# Django -- form validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model that can access Api and return json data

```
class Video(models.Model):
   url = models.URLField(_('URL'), blank=True)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

   def get_oembed_info(self, url):
      api_url = 'http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?'
      params = {'url': url, 'format': 'json'}
      fetch_url =  'http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?%s' % urllib.urlencode(params)
      result = urllib.urlopen(fetch_url).read()
      result = json.loads(result)
      return result

  def get_video_info(self):
     url = self.url
     result = self.get_oembed_info(url)
     KEYS = ('type', 'title', 'description', 'author_name')
     for key in KEYS:
       if result.has_key(key):
          setattr(self, key, result[key])

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if not self.pk:
        self.get_video_info()

     super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def clean(self):
    if not self.cleaned_data['url'] and not self.cleaned_data['slide_url']:
      raise forms.ValidationError('Please provide either a video url or a slide url')
    return self.cleaned_data
```

I want to access the type field while submitting the form, so if the type is other than "something" raise an Error like in the above clean method. Or how can I access get_oembed_info method result in VideoForm Class.

## Solution

Well as Thomas said to call the model's clean method and then do the magic

```
def clean(self):
   self.get_video_info()
   if self.type == 'something':
      raise ValidationError("Message")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ModelForm` is going to [going to call your model's `clean` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L331) during its validation process. That method *can* raise `ValidationError`'s which will be added to your form's errors.

You could therefore implement your validation logic in your model's `clean` method, where the `get_oembed_info` method is available using `self.get_oembed_info()`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas so much for help. It works now very well by calling the model's clean method.